# Showing percentage total in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to create a dataframe showing the numbers from the previous database as a percentage of the total of each row:

```
date      a       b
06-13   249.0   298.0
06-14   238.0   277.0
06-15   4.0 8.0
06-18   302.0   384.0
06-19   270.0   318.0
```

Using the above as an example I would like the 06-13 row to consist of 249 as a percentage of 249+298 etc

I have tried using `.apply(lambda x: 100*x/x.sum())` but this shows the numbers as a percentage of the total (including other rows above and below the given number)

this is my desired output:

```
date      a       b
06-13   0.455   0.535
06-14   0.46    0.56
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Is that what you want?

```
In [21]: df.eval("pct = 100 * a / (a+b)")
Out[21]:
    date      a      b        pct
0  06-13  249.0  298.0  45.521024
1  06-14  238.0  277.0  46.213592
2  06-15    4.0    8.0  33.333333
3  06-18  302.0  384.0  44.023324
4  06-19  270.0  318.0  45.918367
```

---

**UPDATE:**

```
In [28]: df.select_dtypes(['number']).div(df.sum(axis=1), axis=0)
Out[28]:
          a         b
0  0.455210  0.544790
1  0.462136  0.537864
2  0.333333  0.666667
3  0.440233  0.559767
4  0.459184  0.540816
```

Comment: I would like to show 'a' as a percentage of the total in that row and 'b' as a percentage of the total in the row

Comment: @Emm, can you provide your desired / output dataset in the question?

Comment: Added my desired output

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to do that -

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'date' : ['06-13','06-14','06-15','06-18','06-19'],
      'a' : [249,238,4.0,302,270],
      'b' : [298.0,277.0,8.0,384.0,318.0]}

# creates Dataframe.
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

# print the data.
print(df)

df1 = df[['a','b']]
row_sum=df1.sum(axis=1)
df['a']=df['a']/row_sum
df['b']=df['b']/row_sum
print(df)
```

Output -

```
    date      a      b
0  06-13  249.0  298.0
1  06-14  238.0  277.0
2  06-15    4.0    8.0
3  06-18  302.0  384.0
4  06-19  270.0  318.0
    date         a         b
0  06-13  0.455210  0.544790
1  06-14  0.462136  0.537864
2  06-15  0.333333  0.666667
3  06-18  0.440233  0.559767
4  06-19  0.459184  0.540816
```